# Sourcing So many R scripts

Tags: r

I have lots of .r scripts that I want to source all. I have written a function like the one below to source.

```
sourcer=function(){
source("wil.r")
source("k.r")
source("l.r")
}
```

Please can any one tell me how to get this codes activated and how to call each one any time I want to use it?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "get this codes activated and how to call each one any time I want to use it?"

Comment: it would be useful if you could add some psudo-imaginary code that you'd like to work.

Comment: What I meant was how to call the scripts. e.g "wil.r"

Comment: what do you mean by call the scripts? When you source, e.g.: `source("wil.r")`; everything in the "wil.r" is evaluated. If you functions in there they are loaded and you can use them like any other function. If your script is doing something else, those things are done when you source them. I guess that's what you mean by "call the script"?

Comment: Just sharing experience, i had a project when i needed to run many codes; R AnalyticFlow was useful to me: [link](http://r-analyticflow.software.informer.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer by @user2885462, if the amount of R code you need to source becomes bigger, you might want to wrap the code into an R package. This provides a convenient way of loading the code, and allows you to add tests, documentation, etc. Reading [the official package writing tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) is a good place to start for that.

Answer (score 0):

For an individual project, I like to have all (or most) of my R functions in separate .r files, all in the same folder: e.g., AllFunctions

Then at the beginning of my main code I run the following line of code, which sources all .r (and other extensions if they exist - which they usually don't) in the AllFunctions folder:

```
for (nm in list.files("AllFunctions", pattern = ".[RrSsQq]$")) source(file.path("AllFunctions", nm))
```

Comment: Thank you but how do I call any of the scripts in the folder AllFunctions.

Comment: When calling `source`, any functions that are listed in the `.R` files are available in the R session, and any non-function code is executed.

Comment: @user3407190 Just run that line of code and all the scripts in the AllFunctions folder will be executed. As Paul said, if they are functions they will be loaded in the R session, if they are not functions, the code will be executed.  I only store functions in the AllFunctions folder. Make sure you set your working directory correctly.